# Java finding latest file in directory from date in file name

Tags: java, spring, file, file-io, nio

I have a directory where I receive files matching pattern `ABC_STOCK_List_YYYYMMDD_YYYYMMDD.csv`.
I am writing a scheduled service in java where I need to check the file is for today;s date and then do my process on that file.

```
ABC_STOCK_List_20200220_20200220.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200219_20200219.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200218_20200218.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200217_20200217.csv
```

I have this so far:

```
private Optional<File> findLatestFile(final String dir) {
    return Stream.of(new File(dir).listFiles())
                 .filter(
                         file -> !file.isDirectory()
                                 && file.getName().startsWith(prefix)
                                 && file.getName().endsWith(".csv")
                                 && isTodaysFile(file)
                 )
                 .findFirst();

}

private boolean isTodaysFile(File file) {
    return false;
}
```

I need help with `isTodaysFile()` that should check the latter `YYYYMMDD` is today's date. It should not only rely on date from file name, but also filesystem `created` or `modified` time that should also be today.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach to this problem. At first, I've created two helper functions, one that retrieves the end date from the filename, and the other one that retrieves the filesystem `modified` time. I don't think it's necessary to check for the `created` time, since always created time is less than or equal to modified date time.

The function that retrieves the file name's end date:

```
private LocalDate getEndDate(File file) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    String fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    String[] fileNameChunks = fileNameWithoutExtension.split("_");
    String endDateAsString = fileNameChunks[fileNameChunks.length - 1];

    return LocalDate.parse(endDateAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```

Next, the function that retrieves the filesystem `modified` date for a file. For this, I'm using the [`Files#getLastModifiedTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) to retrieve the `modified` date:

```
private LocalDate getLastModifiedDate(File file, ZoneId zoneId) {
    try {
        return ZonedDateTime
                .ofInstant(Files.getLastModifiedTime(file.toPath()).toInstant(), zoneId)
                .toLocalDate();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not read file attributes: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

In the end, it's just using calling these functions and performing the validations:

```
boolean isTodaysFile(File file) {
    Clock systemUTCClock = Clock.systemUTC();
    LocalDate localDateNow = LocalDate.now(systemUTCClock);

    LocalDate fileEndDate = getEndDate(file);

    // first check - validate that the file name's end date is today
    if (!fileEndDate.isEqual(localDateNow)) {
        return false;
    }

    LocalDate lastModifiedDate = getLastModifiedDate(file, systemUTCClock.getZone());

    // second check - validate that the modified that is today
    // no need to check the creation date, since creation date is always less or equal to the last modified date
    return lastModifiedDate.equals(localDateNow);
}
```

I'm using `Clock.systemUTC()` and instantiating all dates based on this, to make sure we are always using *UTC*.

- `LocalDate.now(systemUTCClock)`
- `systemUTCClock.getZone()`

If the input files in the directory are:

```
ABC_STOCK_List_20200220_20200220.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200219_20200219.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200218_20200218.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200217_20200217.csv
ABC_STOCK_List_20200305_20200305.csv
```

At the date of writing this, the current date is *03-05-2020*. The output file, when calling `findLatestFile` is:

```
ABC_STOCK_List_20200217_20200305.csv
```

Notes:

- I didn't perform any validations on the file name format. If something is wrong with the format, you may get some errors when retrieving the end date.

Comment: Java `Instants` use UTC as their timezone. But `LocalDate.now()` may not. So do we need to adjust for that, by using `ZonedDateTime` with the relevant zone ID? Otherwise the date of `Instant.now()` may not match the local date.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @andrewjames. I've updated the functions to use `ZonedDateTime` with "UTC" as zone ID.

Comment: `return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Files.getLastModifiedTime(file.toPath())
                                            .toInstant(), zoneId)
                            .toLocalDate();` ??

Comment: then return `return getLastModifiedDate(ZoneId.of("UTC"), file).equals(LocalDate.now());` ?

Comment: Hmm ok, I'll try to write some unit tests for this piece of code.

Comment: @M06H sorry I don't understand, are you suggesting some code changes?

Comment: @AlexandruSomai yes, and do we really need to truncate to day?

Comment: @M06H probably not. But not very sure how `LocalDate.now()` behaves, since we are comparing with another `LocalDate` that was converted from `ZonedDateTime` (what you have suggested). I still need to validate through some unit tests. This Date/Time API is more complicated that I thought :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, relying only on `LocalDate`, so no need for truncation. Note that I'm using the `Clock.systemUTC()` when doing all conversions, to make sure we are always working with UTC. Still having issues with the unit tests, it's quite difficult to mock the `LocalDate.now(Clock)`

Comment: +1 from me - and sorry, I did not mean for my comment to generate all this work for you :-(. By the way, regarding testing, you probably have already seen [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-override-system-time), but I mention it just in case.

Comment: Thanks and no worries, I enjoy doing it. Plus the constructive feedback was helpful. Yep, that's what I was following. I wanted to test it properly, with separate classes for test and src classes. I've went for the `PowerMock` approach, but I loose my mocks as soon as I call the function. If I have everything in the test class it works. Anyway, I'll come back later to it.